# Multi connection to SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am facing an issue since yesterday. I have a SQL Server located on a remote hosting provider. The provider claims that there could be max 5 connections at the same time.

I also have my own developed app. Until now there was only one user using the application and there was no problem with the connection to that database.

Now we got an additional user who will be working with this app from another place. The problem is, when the first user logged in into the program and he's using it, the second user retrieving information on login form that cannot connect to the SQL Server but before application thinking around 30 seconds before that message.

Seems there can be only one conenction at same time and not 5. Can you advise something or is there any test I can do to check it and make sure where I stand?

Comment: is your application closing connections once completed? Open SQL Server connections that arent being use time out after 15 seconds by default.

Comment: You might be opening connections but never closing in your application, expecting that the garbage collector will close it anyways. Are you creating the connection in a `Using...End Using` block? If not, then try doing that.

Comment: does even one sql query occupying one connection towards database?